# How to add batching implicit for client?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, batching

Lets consider following code:

**Client code:**

```
public class MyClient {
    private final MyClientSideService myClientSideService;

    public MyClient(MyClientSideService myClientSideService) {
        this.myClientSideService = myClientSideService;
    }

    public String requestRow(Integer req) {
        return myClientSideService.requestSingleRow(req);
    }
}
```

**Client side service:**

```
public class MyClientSideService {
    private final MyServerSideService myServerSideService;

    public MyClientSideService(MyServerSideService myServerSideService) {
        this.myServerSideService = myServerSideService;
    }

    public String requestSingleRow(int req) {
        return myServerSideService.requestRowBatch(Arrays.asList(req)).get(0);
    }
}
```

**Server side service:**

```
@Slf4j
public class MyServerSideService {
    //single threaded bottleneck service
    public synchronized List<String> requestRowBatch(List<Integer> batchReq) {
        log.info("Req for {} started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            return batchReq.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            log.info("Req for {} finished");

        }
    }
}
```

**And main:**

```
@Slf4j
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClient myClient = new MyClient(new MyClientSideService(new MyServerSideService()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (int m = 0; m < 100; m++) {
                    int k = m;
                    log.info("Response is {}", myClient.requestRow(k));
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

According the logs it takes approximately 4 min 22 sec but it too much. Ithink it might be improved dramatically.  I would like to implement implicit batching. So `MyClientSideService` should collect requests and when it becomes 50(it is preconfigured batch size) or some preconfigured timeout expired then to request `MyServerSideService` and back route result to the clients. Protocol should be synchronous so clients must be blocked until result getting.

I tried to write code using `CountDownLatch`es and `CyclicBarrier`s but my attempts were far from success.

How can I achieve my goal?

### P.S.

If to replace `requestRowBatch` return type `List<String>` from to  `Map<Integer, String>` to delegate request and response mapping to server following works with limititations. It works only if I send <=25 requests

```
@Slf4j
public class MyClientSideService {
    private final Integer batchSize = 25;
    private final Integer maxTimeoutMillis = 5000;
    private final MyServerSideService myServerSideService;
    private final Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(batchSize);
    private final Map<Integer, String> responseMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    private final AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean();

    private CountDownLatch startBatchRequestLatch = new CountDownLatch(batchSize);
    private CountDownLatch awaitBatchResponseLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);


    public MyClientSideService(MyServerSideService myServerSideService) {
        this.myServerSideService = myServerSideService;
    }

    public String requestSingleRow(int req) {
        queue.offer(req);
        if (!started.compareAndExchange(false, true)) {
            log.info("Start batch collecting");
            startBatchCollecting();
        }
        startBatchRequestLatch.countDown();
        try {
            log.info("Awaiting batch response latch for {}...", req);
            awaitBatchResponseLatch.await();
            log.info("Finished awaiting batch response latch for {}...", req);
            return responseMap.get(req);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "EXCEPTION";
        }
    }

    private void startBatchCollecting() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                log.info("Await startBatchRequestLatch");
                startBatchRequestLatch.await(maxTimeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                log.info("await of startBatchRequestLatch finished");

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            responseMap.putAll(requestBatch(queue));
            log.info("Releasing batch response latch");
            awaitBatchResponseLatch.countDown();

        }).start();
    }

    public Map<Integer, String> requestBatch(Collection<Integer> requestList) {

        return myServerSideService.requestRowBatch(requestList);
    }
}
```

### Update

According Malt answer I was able to develop following:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyClientSideServiceCompletableFuture {
    private final Integer batchSize = 25;
    private final Integer maxTimeoutMillis = 5000;
    private final MyServerSideService myServerSideService;
    private final Queue<Pair<Integer, CompletableFuture>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(batchSize);
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public MyClientSideServiceCompletableFuture(MyServerSideService myServerSideService) {
        this.myServerSideService = myServerSideService;
    }

    public String requestSingleRow(int req) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        lock.lock();
        try {
            queue.offer(Pair.of(req, future));
            int counter = this.counter.incrementAndGet();
            if (counter != 0 && counter % batchSize == 0) {
                log.info("request");
                List<Integer> requests = queue.stream().map(p -> p.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                Map<Integer, String> serverResponseMap = requestBatch(requests);
                queue.forEach(pair -> {
                    String response = serverResponseMap.get(pair.getKey());
                    CompletableFuture<String> value = pair.getValue();
                    value.complete(response);
                });
                queue.clear();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception";
        }
    }


    public Map<Integer, String> requestBatch(Collection<Integer> requestList) {

        return myServerSideService.requestRowBatch(requestList);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work if size is not multiple of batch size

Comment: Perhaps try something like [CoalescingBulkloader](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/examples/coalescing-bulkloader/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/examples/coalescing/bulkloader/CoalescingBulkloader.java), which lets a cache implicitly batch calls.

Comment: @BenManes Do you mean to build my solution based on idea from the source you linked or you mean that I should use the library you linked directly to build solution?

Comment: Either would be fine. That code follows a similar idea as proposed by @Malt. It is a contributed example, not part of the library, so not directly supported. There are also libraries like `Reactor` which could be of interest.

Comment: @Ben Manes Frankly speaking I didn't get how to apply it for my example. could you please provide more details please?

Comment: @Ben Manes, please take a look on topic update

Comment: @Ben Manes, please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725718/2674303

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CompletableFuture`.
Have threads calling `MyClientSideService` put their request in a `Queue` (possibly `BlockingQueue`, and get a new `CompletableFuture` in return. The calling thread can call `CompletableFuture.get()` to block until a result is ready, or go on doing other things.

That `CompletableFuture` will be stored together with the request in `MyClientSideService`. When you reach 50 requests (and therefore 50 `CompletableFuture` instances), have the client service send the batch request.

When the request is complete, use the `CompletableFuture.complete(value)` method of each `ComplatableFuture` instance in the queue to notify the client thread that the response is ready. This will unblock the client if it has called blocking method like `CompletableFuture.get()`, or make it return instantly with value if called later.

Comment: At this case MyClient should expect Future[String] instead of String if I understood you correct. Also I don't see how to execute tail of queue if I subimit 99 task then last 49 won't be executed at all

Comment: please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58725718/2674303

Answer (score 0):

If to replace requestRowBatch return type from `List<String>` with `Map<Integer, String>` to delegate request and response mapping to server I was able to crete following solution:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyClientSideServiceCompletableFuture {
    private final Integer batchSize = 25;
    private final Integer timeoutMillis = 5000;
    private final MyServerSideService myServerSideService;
    private final BlockingQueue<Pair<Integer, CompletableFuture>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition requestAddedCondition = lock.newCondition();


    public MyClientSideServiceCompletableFuture(MyServerSideService myServerSideService) {
        this.myServerSideService = myServerSideService;
        startQueueDrainer();
    }

    public String requestSingleRow(int req) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        while (!queue.offer(Pair.of(req, future))) {
            log.error("Can't add {} to the queue. Retrying...", req);
        }
        lock.lock();
        try {
            requestAddedCondition.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception";
        }
    }

    private void startQueueDrainer() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            log.info("request");
            while (true) {
                ArrayList<Pair<Integer, CompletableFuture>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
                if (queue.drainTo(requests, batchSize) > 0) {
                    log.info("drained {} items", requests.size());
                    Map<Integer, String> serverResponseMap = requestBatch(requests.stream().map(Pair::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    requests.forEach(pair -> {
                        String response = serverResponseMap.get(pair.getKey());
                        CompletableFuture<String> value = pair.getValue();
                        value.complete(response);
                    });
                } else {
                    lock.lock();
                    try {
                        while (queue.size() == 0) {
                            try {
                                log.info("Waiting on condition");
                                requestAddedCondition.await(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                log.info("Waking up on condition");
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }


    public Map<Integer, String> requestBatch(Collection<Integer> requestList) {
        return myServerSideService.requestRowBatch(requestList);
    }
}
```

It looks like a working solution. But I am not sure if it is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your MyClientSideServiceCompletableFuture solution, will send the requests to the server every time you add something to the queue and doesnt wait for requests to be batch sized. You are using BlockingQueue and adding the uneccessary blocking condition and locks. BlockingQueue has blocking-timeout capabilites so no addition condition is neccessary.

You can simplify your solution like this:

It sends requests to server only when the batch is full or the timeout passed and batch is not empty.

```
private void startQueueDrainer() {

        new Thread(() -> {
            log.info("request");
            ArrayList<Pair<Integer, CompletableFuture>> batch = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    batch.clear(); //clear batch
                    long timeTowWait = timeoutMillis;
                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    while (timeTowWait > 0 && batch.size() < batchSize) {
                        Pair<Integer, CompletableFuture> request = queue.poll(timeTowWait , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        if(request != null){
                          batch.add(request);
                        }
                        long timeSpent = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                        timeTowWait = timeTowWait - timeSpent;
                    }

                    if (!batch.isEmpty()) {
                        // we wait at least timeoutMillis or batch is full
                        log.info("send {} requests to server", batch.size());
                        Map<Integer, String> serverResponseMap = requestBatch(batch.stream().map(Pair::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                        batch.forEach(pair -> {
                            String response = serverResponseMap.get(pair.getKey());
                            CompletableFuture<String> value = pair.getValue();
                            value.complete(response);
                        });
                    } else {
                        log.info("We wait {} but the batch is still empty", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Change the method requestSingleRow to not use lock

```
  public String requestSingleRow(int req) {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        while (!queue.offer(Pair.of(req, future))) {
            log.error("Can't add {} to the queue. Retrying...", req);
        }

        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception";
        }
    }
```